# How to get variable value from inside a stored procedure in DB2?

Tags: db2

This seems like it should be very easy...anyway, it is in MS SQL Server

In a DB2 stored procedure, how can I just get the value of a variable?  Say I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE etl.TestABC( 
) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
  BEGIN 
    declare      Stmt              varchar(2048); 
    set Stmt = 'this is a test';
-- print Stmt;
-- select Stmt;


    return 0; 
END @
```

I'd like to print out the value of Stmt after I set it.  Print doesn't work, select doesn't work.  Somebody said I have to insert it to a table first, and then get it after I run the stored procedure.  Is this really necessary?

Thanks,
Sylvia

EDIT: I should have made clearer that I want to see the value of Stmt each time after I set it, and I may need to set it multiple times within the same stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see the values while you're developing / testing your stored procedure, then you should use IBM Data Studio and debug your stored procedure.  This provides normal debugger functionality, so you can see the value of variables as your procedure executes.

If, however, you just want to execute your stored procedure and see a history of values, I suggest creating a global temporary table, and inserting a row into it in your code:

```
declare global temporary table StmtHistory (
  when timestamp not null with default current timestamp, 
  stmt varchar(2048) not null
  ) on commit preserve rows;
```

Then, at points in your stored procedure, add:

```
insert into session.StmtHistory (stmt) values (stmt);
```

After you execute your stored procedure, you can query the table `session.StmtHistory` and see the values you're looking for.

Also, DB2 9.7 added Oracle compatibility, so if you are using this version you may actually be able to use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES to accomplish this, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Ian.  We've been writing to temp tables to get the values, but will try the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE method.  
There appears to be complete instructions here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0302izuha/0302izuha.html#download

Answer (score 3):

you must declare the variable in the constructor of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE etl.TestABC(
    OUT Stmt varchar(2048)
) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN 
    --    declare      Stmt              varchar(2048); 
    set Stmt = 'this is a test';
    -- print Stmt;
    -- select Stmt;

    return 0;
END @
```

This will allow you to access it i.e. from the console:

```
call etl.TestABC(?)
```

with output similar as this:

```
Value of output parameters

Parameter Name  : STMT
Parameter Value : this is a test

Return Status = 0
```

---

*NB:* I don't have a access to our DB2 server at the moment, but I believe that the above should do the trick. Examples based on:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc/doc/t0007055.htm

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What if I'm going to be modifying the variable at multiple points in the stored procedure, and want to output the value at each point?  It seems like the above would just output the last value of the variable if I'm reading it right...

Comment: Correct, this leaves you with the final state of the variable after the procedure finishes running. I'm afraid that I don't know a way how to get interim values other than (1) using multiple OUT variables; (2) splitting your single procedure into multiple ones (where each one would give you its own end value); or (3) storing interim results in some table. I (personally) don't think that you can natively expose procedure's internal variables in PL/SQL other than by setting them as OUT variables. More experienced folks: please advise if there is a better way, I'd be interested in that too. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following line:

```
values Stmt;
```

Comment: I get the following "
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "values (Stmt);
values Stmt" was found following "

Comment: it looks like something else is funky there. Where does the `values (Stmt)` comes from? you can also try something like `select * from (values '34') foo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logging system like 'log4db2' that allows you to write messages in a table or file. The messages are controlled by loggers that can be active or inactive.

With log4db2 you do not need to delete you debugging messages that could be use in the future. You just deactivate the associate logger, or reduce the logging level, exactly as you do with 'log4j'

Check that utility at: https://github.com/angoca/log4db2